Does height of an ideal and collection of minimal primes over that ideal remain invariant under extension of polynomial ring?
Let $I$ be an ideal in $K[x_1,...,x_k]$ where $K$ is a field and $I_1 = (f_1,..,f_t)$ where $f_i$'s are polynomial in $K[x_1,...,x_k]$.
Now considering
the same $f_i$'s as elements of $K[x_1,..,x_n]$  where $(n > k )$
assume $I_2 = (f_1,...,f_t)$.
Then is it true that ht $I_1 =$ ht $I_2$ ?
And also is it true that Min $(I_1) =$ Min $(I_2)$ ?
Consider a commutative ring $A$ with unity and assume $I$ to be an ideal of $A$ and $P$ as a prime ideal of $A$.
Min $(I)$ is defined as the collection of all prime ideals of $A$ which are minimal among all prime ideals containing $I$.
And $\text{ht (P)} $:=$ \hspace{0.1cm} \text{Sup} \hspace{0.1cm} \{n : P_0\subsetneq P_1\subsetneq \dots \subsetneq P_n=P\ \text{where $P_i$'s are primes}\}$
$\text{ht I} $:=$ \hspace{0.1cm} \text{inf} \hspace{0.1cm}\{  \text{ht $P$}: \text{P} \in \text{Min} (I)\}$

The answer to both questions is yes.  This follows from the facts:
(a) If $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then the minimal prime ideals over $I[x]=IR[x]$ are the primes $P[x]$ for the primes $P$ minimal over $I$
and
(b) the height of a prime ideal $P$ in $R$ equals the height of $P[x]$ in $R[x]$.
Fact (b) is Theorem 149 in Commutative Rings by Irving Kaplansky and also Exercise 10.2 (p. 242) in Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry by David Eisenbud.  Fact (a) follows from this observation: if $Q$ is a prime ideal of $R[x]$ containing $I[x]$, then $Q\cap R$ contains $I$.  Thus $Q\cap R$ contains a prime $P$ minimal over $I$, whence $Q$ contains $P[x]$.
